# parts for autoleveling Prusa i3

Tags: ramps-1.4, prusa-i3

I am following this video series to add auto-leveling to my Prusa i3.  https://youtu.be/awsI9bMndJA

I have printed the parts I need and have the servo and ss-5 endstop in my cart at Amazon.  What I need to know is what wiring I need to connect the endstop to the RAMPs board?  I bought this printer as a kit and all parts were included so I am learning slowly.

The switch
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00HPLBAYW?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=ox_sc_act_title_3&smid=AZHZ102UTKBMA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HPLBAYW)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need some wires, nothing special about them. You can use any wire that's flexible enough. For the endstop you'll need 2 wires, for the servo (if you need to extend the cable) 3. The connectors on the end are known as dupont connectors.

Comment: Thanks.  I am new to 3D printing and electronics in general but I have always been interested.  I went on Amazon and bought connectors, crimper, wire (different colors), soldering iron, etc.  Now I will be unstoppable!

Comment: Let us know how it works out -- others (including me) will be interested in perhaps doing the same.

Comment: @TextGeek I bought the stuff and became a connector-making fool.  I ended up making many extension cables as I keep moving things around.  Then i started soldering them and using shrink tubing instead. :D